# Need a Windows batch script that will telnet into a server and run a command

Tags: windows, batch-file

Looking for Windows batch file which will telnet to one IP address, automatically provide username & password which is specified in batch file, execute some series of commands and exit from telnet.

```
@echo off
SET username=abc
SET password=xyz@1234
SET servername=192.168.1.40

echo user %username%> telnetcmd.dat
echo %password%>> telnetcmd.dat
echo adbd^& >> telnetcmd.dat
echo exit>> telnetcmd.dat
telnet %servername% < telnetcmd.dat

del telnetcmd.dat
```

Here I am trying to do telnet to IP with username & password. After successful login it should execute adbc& (This will run necessary service in background) command and exit command. **Once I complete this batch file and if I check adbc service running on server or not it is showing not running on server**.

Output I am getting after completion of batch file.

```
Welcome to Microsoft Telnet Client

Escape Character is 'CTRL+]'


c:\Users\vshah\Desktop>
```

Expected Output:

```
root@pqrs:/ # ps | grep adbd
shell     31899 31828 1348   148   ffffffff 00013348 S adbd
```

Actual Output after executing batch file:

```
root@pqrs:/ # ps | grep adbd
1|root@pqrs:/ #
```

Kindly help me on this to achieve this scenario.

Thank your very much in advance.

Comment: Once batch file completed it showing me following things in cmd

Welcome to Microsoft Telnet Client

Escape Character is 'CTRL+]'


c:\Users\vshah\Desktop>


When I check process running on server or not it is showing that process is not running on server

Comment: Did you already try without "@echo off" in order to see if there are any error messages on your machine, and did you already check on the other machine if you manage getting logged in there?

Comment: From the question I don't understand what service is expected to handle the original telnet contact nor on which port. But I probably don't understand telnet very well as I've mostly only used it for email.

Comment: I have tried it without @echo Off but getting same result. No change in result.

Comment: Telnet needs to execute on default port which is 23 that is reason I have not specified in batch file. I have updated batch file with port number bet still getting same result.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use Telnet as some kind of Windows version of SSH and I don't think telnet on Windows allows you to execute shell commands like that. Also on Windows I'm not aware that '&' can be used to run a service in the background, that is a nix convention. You might need a completely different approach to achieve your goal on Windows.

Comment: Perhaps start here: https://4sysops.com/archives/three-ways-to-run-remote-windows-commands/

Comment: Please read the entire [tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how this site works!

Comment: Is the server running Telnet Server, it is not installed by default? Does passive mode work, as it is meant to be firewall friendly? Windows Telnet does do passive mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not actually a batch, but rather a vbscript, and it uses sleep, so in high latency situations, it easily fail, but I have used the following script to test sending email via telnet

```vbs
smtpadr = InputBox("SMTP server address", "","192.168.1.35" , 100, 200)
localname = InputBox("SMTP", "","mx01.domain.com" , 100, 200)
emailadr = InputBox("Email address", "","jonbdk@domain.com" , 100, 200)
if smtpadr & "" = "" OR localname & "" = "" OR emailadr & "" = "" then
    wscript.quit
end if

set Shell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Shell.run "cmd /K"
wscript.sleep(1000)
sendkeys ("telnet "&smtpadr&" 25{ENTER}")
wscript.sleep(4000)
'sendkeys ("quit{ENTER}")
sendkeys ("HELO "&localname&"{ENTER}")
wscript.sleep(2000)
sendkeys ("MAIL FROM:<"&emailadr&">{ENTER}")
wscript.sleep(1000)
sendkeys ("RCPT TO:<"&emailadr&">{ENTER}")
wscript.sleep(1000)
sendkeys ("DATA{ENTER}")
wscript.sleep(1000)
sendkeys ("FROM:<"&emailadr&">{ENTER}")
wscript.sleep(100)
sendkeys ("TO:<"&emailadr&">{ENTER}")
wscript.sleep(100)
sendkeys ("Date:16-05-2010{ENTER}")
wscript.sleep(100)
sendkeys ("{ENTER}")
wscript.sleep(100)
sendkeys ("Hello World{ENTER}")
wscript.sleep(100)
sendkeys (".{ENTER}")


function sendkeys (strkeys)
on error resume next
' BACKSPACE {BACKSPACE}, {BS}, or {BKSP} 
' BREAK {BREAK} 
' CAPS LOCK {CAPSLOCK} 
' DEL or DELETE {DELETE} or {DEL} 
' DOWN ARROW {DOWN} 
' END {END} 
' ENTER {ENTER} or ~ 
' ESC {ESC} 
' HELP {HELP} 
' HOME {HOME} 
' INS or INSERT {INSERT} or {INS} 
' LEFT ARROW {LEFT} 
' NUM LOCK {NUMLOCK} 
' PAGE DOWN {PGDN} 
' PAGE UP {PGUP} 
' PRINT SCREEN {PRTSC} 
' RIGHT ARROW {RIGHT} 
' SCROLL LOCK {SCROLLLOCK} 
' TAB {TAB} 
' UP ARROW {UP} 
' F1 {F1} 
  shell.sendkeys(strKeys)
if err.number <> 0 then debug "Failed to sendkeys """ & strkeys &""""
on error goto 0
end function
```